# Error saving model in Django Admin with many FK objects pointing to it

Tags: django, django-admin, django-2.2

Using Django==2.2.4

Example of the problem using fake models, in a fake `parties` Django app:

```py
class CakeModel(models.Model):
    . . .

class CandleModel(models.Model):
    . . .
    cake = models.ForeignKey(
        'parties.CakeModel',
        related_name='candles',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )
    . . .
```

The Django admin page:

```py
class CandleModelAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.CandleModel
    extra = 0
    fields = [..., some_field, ...]

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        '''Override to display less items in the admin page'''
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        # exclude some items from the QuerySet
        return limited_qs

@admin.register(models.CakeModel)
class CakeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_select_related = True
    inlines = (..., CandleModelAdmin, ...)

    list_display = (..., some_field, ...)
```

There is no issue when a `CakeModel` has few `CandleModel` pointing to it. I have a few that have about 700, and I am testing with fake 1000.
Whenever I save the page, it will take forever to save (30+ seconds) and sometimes timeout and display an error page.
What can I do to prevent the `CakeModel` admin page from erroring out when edit a `CakeModel` field, and click `"save"` or `"save and continue editing"`?
I might need to add another `CandleModel` as well, or edit a `CandleModel`.

I tried overriding `save_model()`, `save_related()`, `response_change()`, but not sure how to proceed.

Thank you!

Comment: Just don't show the candles as editable models in the cake model admin. Only show links to them, so that when you save a `Cake` you don't also save all associated `Candles`.

Comment: Also, your inlines should be pointing to an [`InlineModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) not to a `ModelAdmin`.

Comment: @dirkgroten correct - copy-paste changed to `admin.TabularInline`. 
I need the candles as editable models, and be able to add more in the admin

Comment: You can edit them when you click on them. You can’t have that many inlines without the issues you mention. Django has a limit of max 1000 fields that can be posted (which you can change btw) but you won’t be able to speed up the saving process.

Comment: I will try doing what you suggest - it might resolve the issue. However - is there a way to override one of the methods I mentioned above and avoid saving all of the Candles?